# How to call a javascript function for an external jsRender Template (formatting a date)

Tags: javascript, jsrender

To make things simple say i have to following external jsRender Template (tmpl.htm):

```
<tr>
    <td>{{=MyDate}}</td>
</tr>
```

How do you call an external javascript function from within the template. Specifically what i'm trying to do is format the date with datejs. I've tried to embed the function within the template but it doesn't work. I'm hoping i don't have to transform the json before i pass it into the render function of jsrender. The dates are formatted as following: /Date(-62135575200000)/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this page http://borismoore.github.com/jsrender/demos/step-by-step/10_helper-functions.html

```
            {{#each Languages}}
                 {{=$ctx.format(Name, "upper")}}{{#if $ctx.nextToLast($view)}} and {{else $ctx.notLast($view)}}, {{/if}}
            {{/each}}
```

Comment: Thanks Anderson. That was it. Not sure i 100% understand the syntax '$ctx.' & '$.views.registerHelpers' but it seems to work. Hopefully as it because more mature i will find the answer :).

Comment: In the recent beta candidate, the syntax is a lot simpler: ~format(...). Here is an example: http://borismoore.github.com/jsrender/demos/step-by-step/09_helper-functions.html.